# Intersection of sets of ranges in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write a Scheme function that will find the intersection of sets that contain pairs representing ranges.

for example, lets say `set1 = ((1 3) (5 13) (25 110) (199 300))`

and `set2 = ((2 4) (17 26) (97 100) (110 200) (288 500))`

so a Scheme function `(intersect set1 set2)` should give the result

`((2 3) (25 26) (97 100) (110 110) (199 200) (288 300))`

Note that I am not trying to find the intersection of the set elements but rather the overlapping points of the pairs in the sets.

This is what I have tried so far

```
(define (intersect a b)
  (cond
    ((or(null? a)(null? b))(quote ()))
    ((and(>=(cadr(car a))(car(car b)))(>=(cadr(car a))(cadr(car b))))
       (cons(cons (car(car b))(cdr(car b)))
         (intersect (cdr a)(cdr b))))
    ((>=(cadr(car a))(car(car b)))
       (cons(cons (car(car b))(cdr(car a)))
         (intersect (cdr a)(cdr b))))
    ((>=(cadr(car a))(car(car(cdr b))))
       (cons(cons (car(car(cdr b)))(cdr(car a)))
         (intersect (cdr a)(cdr b))))
    ((>=(cadr(car b))(car(car(cdr a))))
       (cons(cons (car(car(cdr a)))(cdr(car b)))
         (intersect (cdr a)(cdr b))))
    (else(intersect (cdr a) (cdr b)))))
```

but I got the output as `((2 3) (25 26) (97 100) (110 200))` which is not correct as I should be getting `((2 3) (25 26) (97 100) (110 110) (199 200) (288 300))`.

Anybody has any suggestions on how to solve this or what is wrong in my code.

Comment: I am trying to understand your operation. If `set1` has `(a b)` and `set2` has `(c d)`, then you want to return `((ints a c) (ints a d) (ints b c) (ints b d))`. However, if any of the intersections results in an empty interval, leave that out of the returned value. Is that correct?

Comment: car of car is caar. cadr of cdr is caddr. :)

Comment: For anyone finding this question, there's a related one that might be of interest: [Union of set of ranges in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22292111/1281433).

Comment: @RSahu basically i am trying to get the overlapping points of the ranges. so when (1 3) and ( 2 4) intersect i get (2 3) because that is where the ranges overlap. if there are no overlapping points then don't do anything. hope this clarifies it a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;; Function to compute the intersection of two intervals.
;; If the intersection is empty, the function returns #f as the lower limit
;; of the intersection.
(define (intersect-interval a b)

  ;; Assume that (car a) <= (cadr a) and (car b) <= (cadr b)

  ;; Get the lower limit of the intersection.
  ;; If there isn't one, return #f
  (define (lower-limit)
    (if (< (cadr a) (car b))
      #f
      (car b)))

  ;; Get the upper limit of the intersection.
  (define (upper-limit)
    (min (cadr a) (cadr b)))

  ;; Let's make our life simpler.
  ;; Make sure that (car a) is less than (car b)
  ;; for the core computation.

  (if (> (car a) (car b))
    (intersect-interval b a)
    (list
      (lower-limit)
      (upper-limit)))
  )

;; Function that computes the valid intersections of two sets of intervals.
(define (intersect-interval-sets seta setb)

  ;; Helper function that takes one item from the first set and iterates over the
  ;; items of the second set. It computes the intersection of the item from the first set
  ;; and each item of the second set. If there is a valid intesection, it adds it to the output.
  (define (make-intersections-2 item lst2 out)
    (if (null? lst2)
      out
      (begin
        (let ((ints (intersect-interval item (car lst2))))
          (if (eq? #f (car ints))
            (make-intersections-2 item (cdr lst2) out)
            (make-intersections-2 item (cdr lst2) (append out (list ints))))))))

  ;; Helper function that iterates over the items of the first list and calls the previous
  ;; function using each item of the first list and the second list.
  (define (make-intersections-1 lst1 lst2 out)
    (if (null? lst1)
      out
      (make-intersections-1 (cdr lst1) lst2 (make-intersections-2 (car lst1) lst2 out))))

  ;; Start the recursion and return the result.
  (make-intersections-1 seta setb '())
  )
```

Testing at [repl.it](http://repl.it/languages/Scheme)

```
   (define seta '((2 3) (100 200)))
   (define setb '((5 10) (90 120) (110 300)))
   (intersect-interval-sets seta setb)
=> ((100 120) (110 200))
```

Comment: the ranges in each set are probably assumed non-overlapping, in increasing order of `car`.

Comment: @xmantra23, I didn't think about that. Not sure how I would change the functions to take advantage of that fact.

Comment: i guess wouldn't hurt to check though

Answer (score 1):

This will be easier to handle if we create a special auxiliary function to find an intersection of two given regions, producing an intersection region and the left-over region as the result:

```
(define (intersect xs ys)
  (define (intersect-regions x y)   ; x=(a b) y=(c d), a <= c is assumed NB!
    (let ((b (cadr x)) (c (car y)) (d (cadr y)))  
      (cond
        ( (< b c)            ; 1st region ends before 2nd begins
            (list '()        ; no intersection
                   y))       ; the left-over region
        ( (< b d)            ; thus b >= c, and so, if b < d,
            (list (list c b)      ; b already included: this will
                  (list b d)))    ;  only work for sorted range-lists
        (else                     ; b >= d
            (list y               ; includes d -- will only work for
                  (list d b))))))     ; sorted, 
  (define (loop a b acc)              ;   non-overlapping range-lists
    (if (or (null? a) (null? b))   
      (reverse acc)
      (let ((r (if (<= (caar a) (caar b))
                 (intersect-regions (car a) (car b))
                 (intersect-regions (car b) (car a)))))
          (if (not (null? (car r))) 
             (set! acc (cons (car r) acc)))
          (if (or (null? (cdr a)) (< (cadadr r) (caadr a)))
             (loop (cons (cadr r) (cdr a))  (cdr b)  acc)
             (loop (cdr a)  (cons (cadr r) (cdr b))  acc)))))
  (loop xs ys '()))
```

The function `loop` is tail recursive, building up its result in an accumulator argument. We assume each range-list contains non-overlapping ranges in ascending order. Testing:

```
(intersect '((1 3) (5 13) (25 110) (199 300)) 
           '((2 4) (17 26) (97 100) (110 200) (288 500)))
;Value 18: ((2 3) (25 26) (97 100) (110 110) (199 200) (288 300))
```